# How to convert label to textbox?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Hi I want to convert label field to textbox on image click event.
My html file is

```
<div>
    <div id="tagCust">Customer Details<img src="images/edit.png" class="alignright"/></div>
</div>

<div id="contactdetail">
    <div id="contactInfo">
        <label for="emailid" class="contactText" data-inline="true">Email Id*</label>
    </div>
         <label for="mobileno" class="contactText" data-inline="true">Mobile No.</br></label>
         <label for="custid" class="contactText" data-inline="true">Customer Id.</label>
</div>
```

I want to convert the `mobileno` and the `emailid` labels to textboxes, when the user clicks on edit image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot really "convert" it, but you can either `.replaceWith()` the label html, or `.hide()` and `.show()` it.

For instance:

```
$('.alignright').on('click', function() {
    $('label.contactText').slice(0,2).each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith( '<input type="text"/>' );
    });
});
```

`.replaceWith` can also address a node reference instead HTML strings. However, this would work in a destructive manner and only makes sense if you don't need to show your labels ever again. Otherwise, create those `<input>` elements the same time you create your `<label>` nodes, just give them the CSS style `display: none`. On click, you can either switch those styles (`none` to block and vice versa) or switch classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the code below or at http://jsfiddle.net/qAZZc/ also i would not remove the label for accessibilty reasons better to append an input and hide the label.

```
$("label").each(function(){
        if(($(this).attr("for") == "emailid")||($(this).attr("for") == "mobileno")){
           $(this).after("<input type='text' id='"+ $(this).attr("for") +"'/>");
           $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

Its also better to add a unique id or class to your button or else .alignright every where will fire your function